# Implementation of factory pattern in Python

Tags: python, factory

I have a question concerning factory pattern in Python.

Basing on the configuration in .ini file I want to use either BasicSession or AdvancedSession. Both classes inherit some common functionality from parent Session class. Decision about creating an instance of some class is taken in SessionFactory.

Please find my implementation below (the code simplified to show only the general idea). What do you think about this implementation? Maybe there is a better approach?

```
class SessionConfig(object):
    def __init__(self, advanced_mode_enabled, param_b):
        self.advanced_mode_enabled = advanced_mode_enabled
        self.param_b = param_b    

class Session(ISession):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method_1(self):
        pass

    def method_2(self):
        pass

class BasicSession(Session):
    def __init__(self, config, a, b):
        self.config = config
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

        self.method_2 # From parent class
        self.method_3
        self.method_1 # From parent class

    def method_3(self):
        pass

class AdvancedSession(Session):
    def __init__(self, config, a, b):
        self.config = config
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

        self.method_2 # From parent class
        self.method_3
        self.method_4

    def method_3(self):
        pass

    def method_4(self):
        pass

class SessionFactory(object):
    def __init__(self, config, a, b):
        if config.advanced_mode_enabled:
            self.session = AdvancedSession(config, a, b)
        else:
            self.session = BasicSession(config, a, b)

    def get_session(self):
        return self.session

config = SessionConfig(True, 20) # in real app values are taken from .ini file
session = SessionFactory(config, 'value_1', 'value_2').get_session()
```

Comment: Why do you want a factory?

Comment: Why not do it in `Session.__new__()`?

Comment: Your implementation looks fine to me, if you need to create instances in multiple places it might make sense to make a reference to the **class** and then make instances based on that reference.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, thanks for the nice idea. I really can replace `SessionFactory` by `Session.__new__()`

Comment: @JETM This is too far exemplified to be reviewable on Code Review. Please [be careful when recommending Code Review](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975/1014587).